# Repeater para muitas linhas

Tags: banco-de-dados, winforms, datagridview, datatable

Estou com um problema em uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo onde tenho um banco de dados com aproximadamente 20 milhões de linhas.

O problema é que o usuário quer ver todas essas 20 milhões de linhas em uma unica tela, mesmo que a barra de rolagem fique enorme, antigamente esta tabela era exportada para o Excel e ele utilizava o Excel para isto mas como no Excel existe a limitação de aproximadamente 1 milhão de linhas eles querem que seja desenvolvida esta aplicação.

Alguma sugestão de como fazer isso de forma que não perca tanta performance?

Comment: já que mencionou o Repeater, não seria WebForms?

Comment: existe um repeater similar ao do webForms para winforms, mas esta pergunta foi para o caso de mudar o topico? caso tenha colocado em topico errado peco desculpas e posso retirar este trecho sem problemas

Comment: Não, caso fosse WebForms iria sugerir o uso de um Infinity Scroll. em todo caso você pode tentar algo semelhante para winForms.

Answer (score 3):

Avise o usuário que não é possível carregar ou exibir "tudo em uma única tela".

## Vamos aos números

Fazendo uma estimativa grosseira, se cada registro no banco ocupasse em média 512 bytes, ele precisaria de aproximadamente 9,5 Gigabytes de memória só para armazenar os dados dessa tela.

Note que muito mais memória seria necessário para renderizar esses elementos em algum componente visual. Claro que é possível usar alguma técnica de paginação em memória, mas ainda assim o desempenho seria sofrível.

Adicione a isso a necessidade de transferir quase 10GB pela rede para carregar a tela por completo. Isso seria quase equivalente a fazer o download de um DVD de dupla face!

## Opções viáveis

O que seria possível é *simular* ou dar a impressão de que todos os dados estão ali.

Dá para usar algum esquema de paginação assíncrona onde o usuário seleciona a página ou algum filtro que limite os dados que ele deseja visualizar e então você carrega somente a quantidade de registros suficientes para preencher a tela.

Se sua consulta for eficiente, a tela será carregada quase que imediatamente, porém haverá um pequeno *delay* entre cada navegação. Algo muito mais tolerável.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que a questão não seria nem de performance, mas sim de usabilidade.

Geralmente, vale mais a pena implementar um bom mecanismo de busca do que fazer isso que está propondo.

**Usabilidade comprometida**

Imagine uma barra de rolagem de 1000 pixels de altura (*quase a altura de um monitor 1600 x 1200*). Isso quer dizer que para cada pixel apontável, haverão `20.000.000 / 1.000` registros => `20.000` registros por pixel.

Acontece que ao rolar até os registros, você vai ir para os primeiros daquela sequência de 20000, você sempre irá mostrar quantos couberem na tela, e o resto dos 20000 fica escondido... ai vem a pergunta: Como você vai fazer para acessar o resto dos 20mil registros? Com a seta do teclado? Com a bolinha de rolagem do mouse? Teclas page down e page up. Isso é inviável. Além do mais, ficar caçando pixels na barra de rolagem já é algo meio contra-produtivo para inicio de conversa.

**Alternativa:**

Proponha algo inteligente, que será útil de verdade para quem pediu. Usuário geralmente é assim, não sabe direito o que quer... ele pensa: preciso ter acesso a qualquer registro, logo coloco todos os registros na mesma tela. Ele não pensa, preciso ter acesso a qualquer registro, logo preciso de uma forma eficaz de chegar até eles, logo preciso de um mecanismo de busca que atenda às minhas necessidades.